# Animación palabra por palabra

Tags: java, android

Hola tengo un proyecto android que me gustaría ponerle una animación a un textview que ponga palabra por palabra hasta que se termine mi string y quede estático, he visto algunos pero solo ponen movimiento no es realmente lo que intento hacer.

esta es la clase que utilizo:

```
public static TextViewAnimator perWord(TextView textView){

    int steps = textView.getText().toString().split(" ").length;

    TextViewAnimator textViewAnimator =
            new TextViewAnimator(textView, new TextEvaluatorPerWord(), new TextInterpolator(steps));
    return textViewAnimator;
}

public TextViewAnimator(TextView textView, TypeEvaluator typeEvaluator, TextInterpolator textInterpolator){

    this.textValueAnimator = new TextValueAnimator(textView, textView.getText().toString());
    textValueAnimator.setEvaluator(typeEvaluator);
    textValueAnimator.setInterpolator(textInterpolator);
}

private static class TextValueAnimator extends ValueAnimator implements ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener {

    private WeakReference<TextView> weakTextView;

    public TextValueAnimator(TextView textView, String text) {

        weakTextView = new WeakReference<>(textView);
        setObjectValues(text);
        addUpdateListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        String text = (String) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        TextView textView = weakTextView.get();
        if(textView != null) {
            textView.setText(text);
        }
    }
}

private static class TextEvaluatorPerLetter implements TypeEvaluator {

    @Override
    public Object evaluate(float fraction, Object startValue, Object endValue) {
        int step = (int) fraction;
        return ((String) endValue).substring(0, step);
    }
}

private static class TextEvaluatorPerWord implements TypeEvaluator {

    private String[] words;
    @Override
    public Object evaluate(float fraction, Object startValue, Object endValue) {

        int step = (int) fraction;
        if(words == null){
            words = ((String) endValue).split(" ");
        }
        String textAtStep = "";
        for (int i = 1; i <= step; i++) {
            textAtStep += words[i-1] + " ";
        }

        return textAtStep;
    }
}

private static class TextInterpolator implements TimeInterpolator {

    private int steps;
    public TextInterpolator(int steps) {

        this.steps = steps;
    }
    @Override
    public float getInterpolation(float input) {
        return input * steps;
    }
}

public void start(){
    textValueAnimator.start();
}
public void cancel(){
    textValueAnimator.cancel();
}
public void end(){
    textValueAnimator.end();
}

@RequiresApi(19)
public void pause(){
    textValueAnimator.pause();
}
@RequiresApi(19)
public void resume(){
    textValueAnimator.resume();
}
@RequiresApi(19)
public boolean isStarted(){
    return textValueAnimator.isStarted();
}
@RequiresApi(19)
public float getAnimatedFraction(){
    return textValueAnimator.getAnimatedFraction();
}
public void setRepeatCount(int value){
    textValueAnimator.setRepeatCount(value);
}
public void setRepeatMode(int repeatMode){
    textValueAnimator.setRepeatMode(repeatMode);
}
public void setDuration(long duration){
    textValueAnimator.setDuration(duration);
}
public void setStartDelay(long startDelay){
    textValueAnimator.setStartDelay(startDelay);
}
public void addUpdateListener(ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener listener){
    textValueAnimator.addUpdateListener(listener);
}
public void removeUpdateListener(ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener listener){
    textValueAnimator.removeUpdateListener(listener);
}
public boolean isRunning(){
    return textValueAnimator.isRunning();
}
public void addListener(Animator.AnimatorListener listener){
    textValueAnimator.addListener(listener);
}
public void removeListener(Animator.AnimatorListener listener){
    textValueAnimator.removeListener(listener);
}
```

y en la clase que intento animar solo pongo estas lineas de código:

```
 textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.intro);
    textViewAnimator = TextViewAnimator.perLetter(textView);
    textViewAnimator.setDuration(5000);
    textViewAnimator.setRepeatCount(1);
    textViewAnimator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
    textViewAnimator.start();
```

cumple con lo que necesito pero después vuelve y vuelve a repetirlo lo cual no permite leer el string que pretendo poner en ese textview  solo lo unico que quiero es que se anime una sola vez y despues quede todo el string sin movimiento.

Comment: listo codigo añadido

Comment: editada, tu usas Java y no JavaScript

Comment: Probaste con setRepeatCount(0) no estoy seguro pero puede funcionar

Comment: woow genial se soluciono.

Comment: setRepeatCount(número de repeticiones), si cambias a setRepeatCount(0)m no habrá repetición para la animación

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que solo una vez se escriba la palabra y quede estático, define la propiedad `setRepeatCount(...)` con valor 0, ya que indicas que no habrá repetición para la animación:

```
 textViewAnimator.setRepeatCount(0);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por cierto la clase `TextAnimator` sería:

( lo comento porque no veo en tu pregunta el método `perLetter()`)

```
import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.TimeInterpolator;
import android.animation.TypeEvaluator;
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;

public class TextViewAnimator {


    private TextValueAnimator textValueAnimator;


    public static TextViewAnimator perLetter(TextView textView){

        int steps = textView.getText().length();
        TextViewAnimator textViewAnimator =
                new TextViewAnimator(textView,
                        new TextEvaluatorPerLetter(),
                        new TextInterpolator(steps));
        return textViewAnimator;
    }

    public static TextViewAnimator perWord(TextView textView){

        int steps = textView.getText().toString().split(" ").length;

        TextViewAnimator textViewAnimator =
                new TextViewAnimator(textView, new TextEvaluatorPerWord(), new TextInterpolator(steps));
        return textViewAnimator;
    }

    public TextViewAnimator(TextView textView, TypeEvaluator typeEvaluator, TextInterpolator textInterpolator){

        this.textValueAnimator = new TextValueAnimator(textView, textView.getText().toString());
        textValueAnimator.setEvaluator(typeEvaluator);
        textValueAnimator.setInterpolator(textInterpolator);
    }

    private static class TextValueAnimator extends ValueAnimator implements ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener {

        private WeakReference<TextView> weakTextView;

        public TextValueAnimator(TextView textView, String text) {

            weakTextView = new WeakReference<>(textView);
            setObjectValues(text);
            addUpdateListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            String text = (String) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            TextView textView = weakTextView.get();
            if(textView != null) {
                textView.setText(text);
            }
        }
    }

    private static class TextEvaluatorPerLetter implements TypeEvaluator {

        @Override
        public Object evaluate(float fraction, Object startValue, Object endValue) {
            int step = (int) fraction;
            return ((String) endValue).substring(0, step);
        }
    }

    private static class TextEvaluatorPerWord implements TypeEvaluator {

        private String[] words;
        @Override
        public Object evaluate(float fraction, Object startValue, Object endValue) {

            int step = (int) fraction;
            if(words == null){
                words = ((String) endValue).split(" ");
            }
            String textAtStep = "";
            for (int i = 1; i <= step; i++) {
                textAtStep += words[i-1] + " ";
            }

            return textAtStep;
        }
    }

    private static class TextInterpolator implements TimeInterpolator {

        private int steps;
        public TextInterpolator(int steps) {

            this.steps = steps;
        }
        @Override
        public float getInterpolation(float input) {
            return input * steps;
        }
    }

    public void start(){
        textValueAnimator.start();
    }
    public void cancel(){
        textValueAnimator.cancel();
    }
    public void end(){
        textValueAnimator.end();
    }

    @RequiresApi(19)
    public void pause(){
        textValueAnimator.pause();
    }
    @RequiresApi(19)
    public void resume(){
        textValueAnimator.resume();
    }
    @RequiresApi(19)
    public boolean isStarted(){
        return textValueAnimator.isStarted();
    }
    @RequiresApi(19)
    public float getAnimatedFraction(){
        return textValueAnimator.getAnimatedFraction();
    }
    public void setRepeatCount(int value){
        textValueAnimator.setRepeatCount(value);
    }
    public void setRepeatMode(int repeatMode){
        textValueAnimator.setRepeatMode(repeatMode);
    }
    public void setDuration(long duration){
        textValueAnimator.setDuration(duration);
    }
    public void setStartDelay(long startDelay){
        textValueAnimator.setStartDelay(startDelay);
    }
    public void addUpdateListener(ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener listener){
        textValueAnimator.addUpdateListener(listener);
    }
    public void removeUpdateListener(ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener listener){
        textValueAnimator.removeUpdateListener(listener);
    }
    public boolean isRunning(){
        return textValueAnimator.isRunning();
    }
    public void addListener(Animator.AnimatorListener listener){
        textValueAnimator.addListener(listener);
    }
    public void removeListener(Animator.AnimatorListener listener){
        textValueAnimator.removeListener(listener);
    }

}
```